# inserting page number in Libreoffice

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

I have created a document in Libreoffice Writer and would like to insert page numbers in the document. I am trying to manually insert the page numbers at each footer. But once i insert a desired page number at the footer, all other pages are marked with the same page number.

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 4):

For automatic page numbers we have a predefined **field** we can insert at any place (including your footer) using the menu item *Insert - Fields - Other*:

[image]

We can define the format of the page numbering as well as an offset in case we do not start numbering with `1`.